# -bash: /bin/bash:: No such file or directory

Tags: windows, bash, vim, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am on Windows 10<sub>v1803</sub>, and i have WSL with Ubuntu installed and working well.

Recently, i was in `vim`, and appending some aliases to my `.bashrc`. After I finished editing, I wanted to exit without saving, did the usual Control-C, and instead of `:q!` I did `!:q` (Yes, silly typos). I realized my mistake, did the correct `:q!` and exited.

I came back  ~1hr later, to make those 2 changes (below) and noticed that on startup, I got the error

```
-bash: /bin/bash:: No such file or directory
```

along with the normal startup

```
suda@suda:~$
```

Everything proceeds normally, but i'm concerned as to what that error means.
And, there is nothing that I could find on this apart from reinstall bash, which i have done 5 times, and makes no difference.

I proceeded to add the 2 aliases to my `.bashrc`, and everything works fine...
Some help as to what is happening here please?

---

And if you're wondering, these were what i was adding onto my `.bashrc`:

```
alias cls="clear"
alias md="mkdir"
```

---

Also, I feel that this won't go under `askubuntu`. If i'm wrong, please do tell me.

---

#### Edit: Here's an image

[image: Error Msg]

Comment: You can debug the shell initialization process with `bash -l -i`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message is:

```
-bash: <file>: No such file or directory
```

Check that your script doesn't start with

```
#!/bin/bash:
```

and that you do not invoke `/bin/bash:` elsewhere, either.

(because, indeed, `bash:` should not exist in `/bin`)

Comment: I've stated that this is not an error during the execution of a script - I did something with `vim` and `.bashrc`.

Comment: @Suda: `.bashrc` *is* a script. It's either there, or in one of the scripts executed from there.

Comment: Here are the contents of my .bashrc: I don't see any line with `#!/bin/bash` [link](https://pastebin.com/zNPB1cY8)

Comment: Last line: `/bin/bash: wq: command not found`. Delete it. It is trying to invoke `/bin/bash:` with parameters `wq:`, `command`, `not` and `found`.

Comment: Thanks! It's fixed. Any idea why (and how) it got there?

Comment: Close as I can tell, you would have to have typed `:r!wq` and pressed Enter in command mode while at the end of the file to do it.

Comment: Ok, probably the reason - Thanks! Anyways, the problem was solved in the comments, so how do i accept an answer? Will you update/edit your answer accordingly, or should i do that ***self-answer your own question*** thing and credit you?

Comment: Updated... I didn't imagine there was a chance that you have actually inserted a whole new rogue `bash` invocation, and the "accidentally inserted a colon" might have been more likely. I was wrong.